# npm script for automatic linting failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, eslint

i want to setup a script which should simple --fix all files like this:

```js
"lint": "eslint --fix vue/**/*.vue && eslint --fix vue/**/*.js"
```

automatic lint all `.vue` and `.js` files inside a vue project.

this wont work unfort.

it gives me a:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! project@1.0.0 lint: `eslint --fix vue/**/*.vue && eslint --fix vue/**/*.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@1.0.0 lint script.
```

anyone a idea?

Comment: Are you able to fix for a single vue file? What you are getting for `--debug --fix vue/**/*.vue`

Comment: fixed with `"lint": "eslint --fix vue/**"` but thanks bro :)

Comment: What you are getting without `&&`?

`eslint --fix vue/**/*.vue eslint --fix vue/**/*.js` . Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `&&` and that should work.  Make the command `vue-cli-service` lint only Vue CLI directory for `.vue` and `.js`. The resulting definition is:

```
"lint": "eslint --fix vue/**/*.vue vue/**/*.js"
```

Comment: i did not used the cli